# Where is the DNSv6 server list stored in Linux?

Tags: linux, dns

In Linux, where is the DNSv6 server list stored? Like in the v4 case, will it be stored in `/etc/resolv.conf`?

Answer (score 3):

[In the same file](http://resin.csoft.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?section=5&topic=resolv.conf)

check the "nameserver" stanza.

> `nameserver`
>
> IPv4 address (in dot notation) or IPv6 address (in hex-and-
>   colon notation) of a name server that the resolver should
>    query.  Scoped IPv6 address notation is accepted as well (see inet6(4) for details).  A non-standard port may be specified
>    using [host]:port syntax.  When a non-standard port is
>   specified the host address must be enclosed in square
>    brackets.  For example:
>
> ```
> nameserver [10.0.0.1]:5353
> nameserver [::1]:5353
> ```

You may be able to go without the brackets, but i think i recall the code was changed to make it expected fro ipv6 addresses. Maybe someone else can confirm that.